# How to disable hover effect after clicking it?

Tags: html, css

I want a css code, which look something like this

```
div:hover {
 some hover effect
}

div:onclick{
 some on click event
 disable hover
}
```

The purpose of this is to disable hover of ALL THE element after I focus on just one.

Comment: I think you will have to use javascript to accomplish this

Comment: Try using `div:active` to overwrite the `div:hover`. Might not work for a div though, but it will work for `a`.

Comment: I agree with @ProfessorAbronsius, you have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:active` pseudo class.

```css
button {
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}

button:hover {
  background:#ff9900;
}

button:active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

If you want the style to remain after you press the button, use `:focus`

```css
button {
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}

button:hover {
  background:#ff9900;
}

button:focus {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below implementation. Remove the class from the div, after clicking using JavaScript.

```js
 var div = document.querySelector(".active")

    div.addEventListener("click", function () {
        div.className = "";
    })
```

```css
.active:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <div class="active">TEXT</div>
```